# How to get audio as response from api

Tags: angular, api, audio-streaming

I have an API which gives audio file as response when I provide Customer Id  as form data for that I declare a function but it's returns error.

So I have tried the below code for getting audio as response from the API

```
GetAudioFile() {
  this.postData5 = new FormData();
  this.postData5.append('customer_id', this.customer_id);
  const headers: HttpHeaders =
    new HttpHeaders({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
  this.httpService.post('api url', this.postData5, {
      headers: headers,
    })
    .subscribe((responseData) => {
      console.log(responseData);
    });
}
```

And It gives Me error like this:

[image: this is an error which is coming]

Comment: The easiest way to create audo object and provide data into it.

Comment: you can use base64 for this purpose, convert audio and video etc into base64 and  use it